# Highcharts : Show ticker on the start of plot

Tags: highcharts

How show Ticker from the start of plot along with the label value?

[image]

I want the ticker to start at the plot and also show the correct value.
I set `pointStart` to start of the x-axis value.

When I set `startOnTick` to true. And for know `tickInterval`to 30 minutes. (tickInterval varies based on the data interval)
[image]
this is what I get.

Any way to show the ticker at the start of the plot.

Comment: you should add your sample code to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tickPositioner` function, for example:

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        startOnTick: true,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%k:%M', this.value);
            }
        },
        tickPositioner: function() {
            var ticks = [],
                dataMin = this.dataMin,
                dataMax = this.dataMax,
                tickInterval = (dataMax - dataMin) / 5;

            for (var i = this.dataMin; i <= this.dataMax; i += tickInterval) {
                ticks.push(i);
            }

            return ticks;
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aswzfrnc/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat

Comment: Solution worked, thanks.
`this.dataMin` and `this,dataMax` would be null, should check for null before looping